# Getting Value Outside Method

Tags: ios, return-value, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a ViewController that has a TableView and I want to Get the value from the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** so i can pass to another view.

This is the Method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    // That's the string that I want to get the value
    NSString *selectRow = [_vinhoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    stringTest = selectRow;
}
```

I create and synthesize the property **stringTest**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringTest;
@synthesize stringTest;
```

to assign the value from **selectRow** but i guess that i'm doing something wrong. Because this doesnt work.

Anybody can help me? Thanks

Comment: So is it `stringTest` or `stringTeste`?

Comment: @sha **stringTest** ! Sorry, typed wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would try to just see if you are assigning a value by nslog

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_vinhoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

Then if you are getting something in the log, you can try

```
self.stringTest = [_vinhoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

if you are storing NSStrings in your array.

Try this,

create your string in AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myTitleString;
```

Now anywhere you want to access this string, you are going to need to include the appDelegate at the top

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

and then use this to access it

```
AppDelegate *AppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

assign it with

```
AppDelegate.MyTitleString = //whatever you are going to assign it with;
```

in your other view controller you will do the same thing, import the appdelegat.h at the top, create the app delegate and give it's value to your title

```
NSString *MyStringInTheDifferentController = AppDelegate.MyTitleString;
```

Comment: I try here and YES, i assigning a value to the `stringTest`
But only works inside the method, if I put the NSLog outside the method, i get a `Null` value.
I want to use outside the method so i can pass to another view.

Comment: 'self.stringTest = [_vinhoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];' should work inside the method. For sure the NSLog statement will not work outside that method because it is using the indexPath that the method provides. Did you try assigning it with 'self.stringTest'?

Comment: Yes, if a put `self.stringTest` I get the value. 
But only inside the method. How i can use outside this method?
So I can use it in another ViewController?

Comment: Once it is assigned from inside the method, I don't see why you would have a problem bringing up the already assigned variable elsewhere inside your class. If you need to pass the variable to another view/class you need to have it stored somewhere else, like in a singleton or in the app delegate.

Comment: I'll try to explain you why i want to use this.
I want to assign the Title of my NavigationController from this value.
When the user click in a row, the another viewcontroller is loaded with other table and the Title of my NavigationController i the same of my select row.

Comment: Yes! Finally works!
I spend a lot of time trying to do this man, thanks very much.
I'm a designer as well, so if you want something some day, just tell me.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following method right after `@synthesize stringTest;`:

```
- (void)setStringTest:(NSString *)stringTest
{
    _stringTest = stringTest; // Insert a breakpoint here
    /* You should see here what value does stringTest have and also who called this setter. */
}
```

I think that this is the best way to debug because you may override the `stringTest` property right after `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and you may not know it.

P.S.: If you don't use **ARC** that setter needs to be updated.

Comment: if a put this method a get an error
`Use of undeclared identifier _stringTest; Did you mean 'StringTest'?`
I use ARC, i'm working on XCode 5 ios7

Comment: Then please update from `@synthesize stringTest;` to `@synthesize stringTest = _stringTest`;

Comment: Okay, now is right. And the `stringTest`is getting the right Value.
But HOW i can use this value in another ViewController? How i can pass this value and use in another ViewController?

Comment: someOtherViewController.someProperty = self.stringTest;

Comment: But Where? Sorry man, i'm very new in this.
If I put the code you said.



`- (void)setStringTeste:(NSString *)stringTeste
{
    _stringTeste = stringTeste;
    // SubTabela is my OtherViewController
    SubTabela *subVC = [[SubTabela alloc] init];
    subVC.tituloTabela = self.stringTeste;
}`



But if i put a `NSLog` in my OtherViewController, in `viewDidLoad` 
I get a `null` value

Comment: The problem is in the SubTabela class and I can't tell which is the problem until I don't see the code from it. Paste that code to **PasteBin** (http://pastebin.com) or some other service like that and I'll have a look.